# corewlan: associate with network using saved system credentials (no sandbox)

Tags: swift, macos, corewlan

I'd like to write a osx app that uses corewlan to associate to a network using saved system credentials.

=> I want to take advantage of the credentials already saved in the system and available to the apple airport menu already, so the user doesnt have to re-enter the password

My app would not be sandboxed (if needed. I guess if there is a chance, than without this :D)

---

to provide some sample / mock code to show what I want to do:

```
  func connect(to name: String) {
      interface?.associate(name: name: password: %%USE_SYSTEM_STORED%%)
  }
```

--
note that reading works fine and if I provide the password again it works too: im mainly asking to associate without pwd / already stored credentials